# Drag/Drop Issue on iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

I am trying to create a drag/drop effect on iPad (using a library based on jQTouch/jQuery UI)

There is a fixed width/height div and I use overflow:auto for the div..So it is something like;

```
div #draggable{
height: 350px;
margin: 0;
overflow: auto;
width: 235px;
}
```

Now while I am able to drag this div, it only drags within the scrollable fixed width/height region...

I actually want it to be dragged outside, as the drop area is outside of this region...

Could you please help me. Thank you.

Also in case you have any other references for iPad Drag/Drop Javascript (apart from Sencha Touch)

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a jQuery UI draggable, you need to make sure the `containment` option is set appropriately, and you need to check the `appendTo` property is set appropriately. In general, setting the latter to `$(document.body)` will work. See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-appendTo

Comment: Yes, I have already done that...Actually the drag/drop is working perfectly on all desktop browsers...Now I want it to work on the iPad (So in a way I am planning to extend the jQuery-UI library with jQTouch or any other touch library)..